# get_template_part calls amount and performance?

Tags: performance, get-template-part

I'm trying to build the theme that is easily customizable by other developers and chose to go `get_template_part` route so files can be easily overwritten in child theme.

My question **is there some kind of limit for `get_template_part` until it hurts performance**?

For example, I'm using it for building a card UI, so each card has 5-10 `get_template_part` calls. If page displays 40 cards, that would be 400 disk lookups — could it hurt the performance? Is it better to move to regular functions (e.g. template tags)?

Comment: My personal opinion: don't worry about that (too much). Create the theme in a way that all pages can easily be page cached, e.g. via getting dynamic content via the REST API instead of putting them on the page itself

Comment: Why do you need 5-10 template parts for a single card? Why can't the child theme just replace the whole card? Is there _that_ much in it?

Comment: @JacobPeattie yeah, the card itself is pretty sophisticated, as it can contain multiple elements as review stars, icons, video and so on. For the ease of editing those were separated and moved outside the card template